# Bash script not killing job as intended?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a simple 20 line little script to restart my `Go` program this is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
chsum1=""
pid=""

while true ; do
  chsum2=$(find ./ -type f -exec md5 {} \;)
  if [[ $chsum1 != [[$chsum2 ]] ; then
    if [[ $pid != "" ]] ; then
      kill $pid
    fi
    go run main.go &
    pid=$(%%)
    chsum1=$chsum2
    echo "RESTARTED"
  fi
  sleep 2
done
```

It works but when it restarts, I get port still in use.

I'm not 100% sure where I went wrong here I don't have much experience with bash

Comment: Kill send a signal to your process, asking to shutdown. I would say, you can try to add a sleep so the process can actually terminate, or use `kill -9`

Comment: The second `[[` in the `if` is superfluous (and if it were correct, it should have a space before `$chsum2`).  Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Also `$(%%)` looks wrong; you seem to want `pid=$!`

Comment: `$(%%)` give the command of the current job, not its PID.  Also remember that `kill` can take a job number, e.g. `kill %1`, it does not have to be a PID (that's why `kill` is a shell built-in).

Answer (score 0):

You have error in line (too many `[[`):

```
if [[ $chsum1 != [[$chsum2 ]] ; then
```

And as for the kill signal, you are sending a gracefull kill (`SIGTERM`), so the application wont' die right away, it will try to stop all its tasks and shutdown, but it might take time.

I would do a small loop that would check if the given pid is still there and do the restart only after pid is really dead:

```
if [[ $pid != "" ]] ; then
  kill $pid
  while ps -p $pid >/dev/null; then
      sleep 1
  done
fi
```

The above code will loop forever, so you might want to try to limit number of loops (e.g. using `for i in seq 100`)

Comment: Depends on the failure mode. If it gets wedged (runs but produces no results) restarting it when it stops to produce output seems like the way to go (though the sophisticated solution would be to fix the bug which causes this behavior).